# Recursion to iteration without rebinding a reference

Tags: c++, recursion

I have a function which, cut down, looks like:

```
// bar is basically a linked list with extra stuff tagged on
void recurses(std::unique_ptr<bar> & P)
{
  bool ok = decide_if_this_P_is_acceptable(P);
  if (!ok)
  {
     recurses(P->getNextPtr());
     return;
  }
  // Now do lots more stuff involving the reference P and P.reset()
}
```

The bar class exposes a method called `getNextPtr()` which returns a `std::unique_ptr<bar>&` which can then be passed back into recurses.

This unfortunately blows the stack for some large inputs. I'd like to convert it to iteration, e.g.

```
void recurses(std::unique_ptr<bar> & P)
{
  bar * N = nullptr;
  for (;;)
  {
    bool ok = decide_if_this_P_is_acceptable(P);
    if (ok)
    {
       break;
    }
    P = P->getNextPtr();
  }
  // P is now OK
  // Now do lots more stuff involving the reference P and P.reset()
}
```

This of course refuses to compile because we can't rebind a reference (`std::unique_ptr<bar> & P`).

How can I lose the recursion while letting the remainder of the function mutate whichever reference was deemed good?

Comment: Why not getting the raw pointer from `P` and working with that?

Comment: I'm not clear on your desired return semantics.  Your recursive version attempts to return the result of the recursive call -- which has a base case of no return value -- and the function type is **void**.  Should that return statement be merely a call without an assignment?

Comment: What is `std::unique_ptr::getNextPtr`?

Comment: @Prune the return is required, i.e. call recurses() but do nothing further. I'll edit the code to make that more obvious

Comment: @user2079303 I may have butchered the example. It's meant to be equivalent to P.get()->getNextPtr()

Comment: What stops you from iterating on a local variable?  My C++ is rusty, but ... I *think* you can create a local ptr, bind it to NextPtr, and iterate on that.  You'll also need a temp ptr to bridge the loop repeating ... clunky, but functional.  On each iteration, you have to destroy the main pointer, recreate it bound to the temp.  In the next iteration, you destroy the temp and create a new one, rebound to main.getNextPtr.

Comment: @JonChesterfield when posting an expamle on SO, create a [mcve]. If the problem occurs at run time, then there should be no compilation errors in your example.

Comment: "blows the stack for some large inputs" - did you compile with -O3? the code looks very close to tail-recursion (which g++ can achieve).  With tail-recursion, stack use is the same as iterative.

Comment: @user2079303 Thanks for the edit

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN TCO would also sort this out, but I'd like to keep coherent debugging information for the other times it segfaults

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to use [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) instead of raw reference. It is rebindable:

```
void recurses(std::reference_wrapper<std::unique_ptr<bar>>& P)
{
  bar * N = nullptr;
  for (;;)
  {
    bool ok = decide_if_this_P_is_acceptable(P);
    if (ok)
    {
       break;
    }
    P = P.get().getNextPtr();
  }
  // P is now OK
  // Now do lots more stuff involving the reference P and P.reset()
}
```

Note the additional `.get()` before the `.getNextPtr()` call, which access the underlying reference first. You'll have to do that on all your member function calls.

Alternatively, you could just use a pointer internally:

```
void recurses(std::unique_ptr<bar>& R)
{
  std::unique_ptr<bar>* P = &R;

  bar * N = nullptr;
  for (;;)
  {
    bool ok = decide_if_this_P_is_acceptable(*P);
    if (ok)
    {
       break;
    }
    P = &P->getNextPtr();
  }
  // P is now OK
  // Now do lots more stuff involving the reference P and P.reset()
}
```

Comment: `while (!decide_if_this_P_is_acceptable(*P))` is a more concise loop

Comment: unique_ptr<bar>* is probably the more obvious answer, I'll go with that. Thanks